# Problem with angular 8 project on Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular8, polyfills

The project is not working on IE.

My dependencies are:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@browninglogic/ng-modal": "^4.0.3",
    "@code-art/angular-globalize": "^8.0.1",
    "cldr": "^5.5.4",
    "cldr-data": "^36.0.0",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-loading-spinner": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

** tsconfig.json** - already tried to change the target to es5 from es2015, but didn't work.

```
 "target": "es5"
```

**polyfills.ts** - also tried to add this, but didn't work

```
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/promise';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? If there is, the error points to which line? You could check if the error occurs in your code or in external js library. Angular CLI doesn't transpile external library code. Besides, Angular 8 doesn't need the polyfills in polyfills.ts.

Comment: there was no errors in the console, but I managed to run it on IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created and a new *ts* file called **zone-flags.ts** in the *src* folder and then import it in **polyfill.ts**

```
(window as any)._Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

**polyfill.ts** - changed it like this helped me:

```
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm i --save classlist.js`.
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm i --save web-animations-js`.
 import './zone-flags.ts';
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
 import 'url-search-params-polyfill'; // Run npm i url-search-params-polyfill
```

and import the **zone-flags.ts** in

```
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/zone-flags.ts"
  ]
```

**browserslist**

```
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```